# How to check the memory size occupied by the streaming data engine?

Tags: dolphindb

Is there a function in dolphinDB to check the memory occupied by the stream data engine?
At present, my streaming data engine is already processing data in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the running status of all engines through the `getStreamEngineStat()`  function.

If you want to query the usage of a specified engine, you can use it like this, for example, to query the running status of all time series engines on the node:

```py
getStreamEngineStat().TimeSeriesEngine
```